# Appium Error:main.js: error: Unrecognized arguments: --no-session-override

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium

I am trying to record  iOS automated Tests using Appium Inspector by instructions using tutorial..

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hv9A9WfYF4g

I have my app on workspace. I built it using iphonesimulator7.0 which showed a sucess message then correctly set the path to the built app on appium inspector. But when i click Launch it shows the error.

```
Appium Error:main.js: error: Unrecognized arguments: --no-session-override
```

on its console..Any idea what might be the problem.

PS:Am using appium for the first time

[image]

above is the screenshot that i get when i click launch button..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether Override Existing Sessions checkbox is checked or not. It should be checked.

Appium -- > Preferences ---> General

Comment: i got the answer long time ago! :p